# Equivalent of LinkedHashMap in in the ObservableMap range

Tags: javafx, linkedhashmap

I am curious as to whether there is an Observable Map in JavaFX that is similar to a Linked Hash Map. The reason for me asking is, I am currently using an ObservableMap, but it does not maintain insertion order, and I need an Observable Map that maintains insertion order.

Comment: Can you clarify the issue you bring up in a comment to fabian's answer? Preferably with a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

You can define the `Map` used to store the data using [`FXCollections.observableMap`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableMap(java.util.Map)):

```
Map<K, V> linkedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
ObservableMap<K, V> observableMap = FXCollections.observableMap(linkedMap);
```

Remember not to do manipulations on the backing map (`linkedMap` in this case), since this does not trigger the listener(s) of the map.

Comment: Yes, that could definitely work. Thank you for the quick reply. 
I do have one more question in this regard. What if it is a map that you constantly add to in a while loop for example, and this loop never terminates, how will you go about that, because even if you add it to the `LinkedHashMap` and then to the `ObservableMap`, the order will still get mixed up.